# Can't call on_state_changed during garbage collection, please be sure to close or use a context manager

Tags: python, scripting, azure-eventhub

I am using Python script for connecting API with Azure Event Hub via websocket protocol. When I run the script, data is being sent until error from the title of this post jumps out and stops execution of the script. I cannot see the origin of the error and that's why I'm confused.
Error says '...please be sure to close or use a context manager.' I wonder which part causes this error and how to possibly solve it.

```
import asyncio
import json
import websockets

#for evh
from azure.eventhub.aio import EventHubProducerClient
from azure.eventhub import EventData


async def cryptocompare():

    producer = EventHubProducerClient.from_connection_string(conn_str="CONN_STR", eventhub_name="EVH_NAME")

    
    # this is where you paste your api key
    api_key = "API_KEY"
    url = "wss://streamer.cryptocompare.com/v2?api_key=" + api_key
    async with websockets.connect(url) as websocket:
        await websocket.send(json.dumps({
            "action": "SubAdd",
            "subs": ["0~Coinbase~BTC~EUR","0~Coinbase~BTC~USD","0~Coinbase~BTC~CHF"],
        }))
        while True:
            try:
                data = await websocket.recv()
            except websockets.ConnectionClosed:
                break
            try:
                #data = json.loads(data)
                event_data_batch = await producer.create_batch()

                # Add events to the batch.
                #for i in data:
                event_data_batch.add(EventData(data))
                # Send the batch of events to the event hub.
                await producer.send_batch(event_data_batch)
                print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
            except ValueError:
                print(data)


asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(cryptocompare())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this error, you can wrap the code where you call the producer with `async with producer:`.

```py
    async with producer:
        while True:
            try:
                data = await websocket.recv()
            except websockets.ConnectionClosed:
                break
            try:
                #data = json.loads(data)
                event_data_batch = await producer.create_batch()

                # Add events to the batch.
                #for i in data:
                event_data_batch.add(EventData(data))
                # Send the batch of events to the event hub.
                await producer.send_batch(event_data_batch)
                print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
            except ValueError:
                print(data)
```

This error occurs when the client is not closed properly, because the sender is still open when trying to garbage collect. More detailed explanation can be found [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/8404#issuecomment-569105737).

Sample of sending with context manager [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/4b8a195e4c06946cb8ecea0d40eda049de04ca2b/sdk/eventhub/azure-eventhub/samples/async_samples/send_async.py#L94).

Comment: Thanks a lot! It helped to solve my problem.